# Como puedo hacer para que registre los retiros y ingreso con if y elif

Tags: python, python-3.x

Intento que cuando ponen un valor en la variable ingreso o retiro, ese valor me salga en la función consulta como impreso "hiciste un ingreso de 200" o "hiciste un retiro de 100", pero ya he intentado poner mayor > o menor <, también igual o mayor a 0, pero no me sale. Acá dejo el código:

```
class cuentaBancaria:
    def __init__(self, titular, numero_de_cuenta, saldo):
        self.titular = titular
        self.numero_de_cuenta = numero_de_cuenta
        self.saldo = saldo

    def inicio(self):
        # Ciclo infinito que únicamente se interrumpe al ingresar "fin"
        while True:
            inicios = input("¿Que tramite quiere realizar?: ").lower()
            if inicios == "ingreso":
                global ingreso
                ingreso = int(input("¿Cuanto quiere ingresar de dinero?: "))
                mensaje = self.ingresos(ingreso)
            elif inicios == "retirar":
                global retiro
                retiro = int(input("Cuanto dinero quieres retirar?: "))
                mensaje = self.retiros(retiro)
            elif inicios == "saldo":
                mensaje = self.saldos()
            elif inicios == "consultar":
                global datose
                datose = []
                if ingreso <= 0:
                 datose = ("No hicistes ningun ingreso")
                elif ingreso > 0:
                 datose.append(f"Hicistes un ingreso de {ingreso}")
                elif retiro <= 0:
                    retiro = 0
                    datose = ("No hicistes ningun retiro")
                elif retiro > 0:
                    datose.append(f"Hicistes un retiro de {retiro}")
                mensaje = self.datos()
            # Condición para terminar el ciclo infinito
            elif inicios == "fin":
                # Finaliza el ciclo while
                break
            else:
                mensaje = "Esta opcion no es validad"
                
            # Mostramos el mensaje obtenido de los métodos de la clase
            print(mensaje)
        return "Gracias por su visita"

    def ingresos(self, cantidad):
        self.saldo += cantidad
        return f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {self.saldo}"

    def retiros(self, cantidad):
        if cantidad > self.saldo:
            mensaje =  "Ud no cuenta con el saldo suficiente"
        else:
            self.saldo -= cantidad
            mensaje = f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {self.saldo}"
        return mensaje

    def saldos(self):
        return f"Tu saldo es: {self.saldo}"
    
    def datos(self):
        global datose
        return datose
    
mi_sueldo = cuentaBancaria("Juan", 199733051214, 1000)
print(mi_sueldo.inicio())
```

Solo he podido hacer que ingreso me salga bien, pero en retiro me sale que la variable no esta definido, acá dejo la impresión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Obvio, si `retiro` no las inicializado dentro del método antes de consultarla con `if`.

Comment: En general la E/S se hace fuera de las clases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema está en que tienes una lista `datose` pero nunca la recorres y por eso no imprime lo demás, deberías iterarla de alguna forma.

Otro problema es que no tienes variables globales, por lo que no necesitas utilizar `global`, cuando utilices clases, lo mejor es utilizar atributos para poder enviar información a los métodos (Funciones) de la clase, por ejemplo, podrías crear un atributo `self.movimientos` que sea una lista y que ahí se vayan guardando todos los movimientos, como si fuera un historial de lo que ha sucedido con la cuenta.

A ese atributo `movimientos` se le adjunta el tipo de movimiento en cada ingreso o retiro y al consultar se podría recorrer la lista para imprimir todos los movimientos.

Ejemplo completo:

```
class cuentaBancaria:
    def __init__(self, titular, numero_de_cuenta, saldo):
        self.titular = titular
        self.numero_de_cuenta = numero_de_cuenta
        self.saldo = saldo
        # Lista para los movimientos
        self.movimientos = []

    def inicio(self):
        # Ciclo infinito que únicamente se interrumpe al ingresar "fin"
        while True:
            inicios = input("¿Qué tramite quiere realizar?: ").lower()
            if inicios == "ingreso":
                ingreso = int(input("¿Cuánto dinero quiere ingresar?: "))
                mensaje = self.ingresos(ingreso)
            elif inicios == "retirar":
                retiro = int(input("¿Cuánto dinero quiere retirar?: "))
                mensaje = self.retiros(retiro)
            elif inicios == "saldo":
                mensaje = self.saldos()
            elif inicios == "consultar":
                # Revisar si hay movimientos
                if self.movimientos:
                    # Imprimir utilizando alineación de texto
                    print('Movimientos'.center(72, '-'))
                    # Recorrer todos los movimientos
                    for movimiento in self.movimientos:
                        # Imprimir utilizando alineación de texto para crear columnas
                        print(f'Tipo de movimiento: {movimiento[0]:<10} Cantidad: {movimiento[1]:>8}     Saldo: {movimiento[2]:>10}')
                    mensaje = 'Fin de los movimientos'.center(72, '-')
                else:
                    mensaje = 'No hiciste ningún movimiento'
                
            # Condición para terminar el ciclo infinito
            elif inicios == "fin":
                # Finaliza el ciclo while
                break
            else:
                mensaje = "Esta opción no es válida"
                
            # Mostramos el mensaje obtenido de los métodos de la clase
            print(mensaje)
        return "Gracias por su visita"

    def ingresos(self, cantidad):
        self.saldo += cantidad
        # Agregar el ingreso a los movimientos
        self.movimientos.append(('Ingreso', cantidad, self.saldo))
        return f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {self.saldo}"

    def retiros(self, cantidad):
        if cantidad > self.saldo:
            mensaje =  "Ud no cuenta con el saldo suficiente"
        else:
            self.saldo -= cantidad
            mensaje = f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {self.saldo}"
            # Agregar el retiro a los movimientos
            self.movimientos.append(('Retiro', cantidad, self.saldo))
        return mensaje

    def saldos(self):
        return f"Tu saldo es: {self.saldo}"
    
    def datos(self):
        global datose
        return datose
    
mi_sueldo = cuentaBancaria("Juan", 199733051214, 1000)
print(mi_sueldo.inicio())
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
¿Qué tramite quiere realizar?:  ingreso
¿Cuánto dinero quiere ingresar?:  10
Tu saldo es ahora de: 1010
¿Qué tramite quiere realizar?:  retirar
¿Cuánto dinero quiere retirar?:  50
Tu saldo es ahora de: 960
¿Qué tramite quiere realizar?:  consultar
------------------------------Movimientos-------------------------------
Tipo de movimiento: Ingreso    Cantidad:       10     Saldo:       1010
Tipo de movimiento: Retiro     Cantidad:       50     Saldo:        960
-------------------------Fin de los movimientos-------------------------
¿Qué tramite quiere realizar?:  fin
Gracias por su visita
```

En la consulta de los movimientos incluí alineación de texto, tal vez no has visto ese tema pero te invito a revisarlo para que tu programa presente la información de forma más atractiva, [aquí](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2020/12/15/python-alinear-rellenar-datos-print/#:%7E:text=Para%20alinear%20texto%20en%20Python,cantidad%20de%20espacios%20en%20blanco.&text=Cada%20valor%20que%20se%20va%20a%20formatear%20est%C3%A1%20encerrado%20entre%20llaves%20%7B%7D%20.) te dejo un artículo que habla sobre el tema.

**Nota extra:** Tu código tenía muchas faltas de ortografía, por ejemplo "hicistes", falta de acentos y signos de puntuación, recuerda que la forma como se presenta la información al usuario es importante.

Comment: Pero las palabras con tilde no son palabras con caracteres especiales

Comment: Buen día @nekordemon, no entendí lo de lo de los caracteres especiales. Si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la respuesta a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Comment: me refiero a simbolos especiales que no pueden salir en str y se tiene que usar u"?"

Comment: y otra consulta, sabes como podría usar csv.writer para guardar los movimiento